# Prove $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{k} x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^{k}dx = n!$

Tags: limits, measure-theory

I need to show the following limit

$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{k} x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^{k}dx = n!$
I tried using the binomial expansion of $(1-x)^k$ but its not leading me anywhere ! 
maybe I need to use DCT ..

Please help !

Comment: As $k\to\infty$, the integral you posted becomes the same as that of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $t=\dfrac{x}{k}$, now the integral is 
$$\int_0^1k^{n+1}t^n(1-t)^k\text{d}t=-\int_0^1\frac{k^{n+1}}{k+1}t^n\text{d}(1-t)^{k+1}$$
Via integration by parts, then we can find
\begin{split}
\int_0^1k^{n+1}t^n(1-t)^k\text{d}t&=n\int_0^1\frac{k^{n+1}}{k+1}t^{n-1}(1-t)^{k+1}\text{d}t\\
&=-n\int_0^{1}\frac{k^{n+1}}{(k+1)(k+2)}t^{n-1}\text{d}(1-t)^{k+2}\\
&=n(n-1)\int_0^{1}\frac{k^{n+1}}{(k+1)(k+2)}t^{n-2}(1-t)^{k+2}\text{d}t\\
&=\cdots\\
&=n!\int_0^1\frac{k^{n+1}}{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)}(1-t)^{k+n}\text{d}t\\
&=n!\frac{k^{n+1}}{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)(k+n+1)}
\end{split}
Thus,
\begin{split}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1k^{n+1}t^n(1-t)^k\text{d}t
&=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}n!\frac{k^{n+1}}{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)(k+n+1)}\\
&=n!
\end{split}
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try using the fact that $\lim_{k\to\infty}(1+r/k)^k=e^r$, along with DCT. To apply DCT, you may want to use the inequality 
$1-x \leq e^{-x}$.